# issue regarding Google Play Services 25.0.0.0

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services

I am new to **Xamarin Android** development.For google plus authentication I am using **Google Play Services**.But when I install Only `Xamarin.Android.GooglePlayservice.Base` and `Xamarin.Android.GooglePlayservice.Plus` it automatically downloads all the google play services.
What is the solution?What should I do to prevent unnecessary packages installation?

Comment: I think you should specific what package of `Google play service` you wanna install. Try to use something like:`Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus -Version 26.0.0`. For more details please refer [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus/).